# Variance Bias Tradeoff decomposition of Linear Regression with a twist

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bias-variance-tradeoff

Normally, for a linear regression problem with fixed observations, we have the variance and bias tradeoff as:
$$Var(Y) + Bias^2 (\hat{\beta_x}) + Var(\hat{\beta_x})$$.
My question is what happens to the bias and variance if $x_i \sim N(0, I_p)$. i.e., what would be $$E_{x\sim N(0, I_p), y|x \sim N(x^T\theta^*, \sigma^2)}[(x^T\theta - y)^2]$$ where the targets is given by $y_i = x_i^T \theta^* + \epsilon_i$, $\theta$ is the estimator.